# How to hide products if out of stock (if variable product - if all variation are out of stock) in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

If all variations are out of stock I want to hide a product.

In WooCommerce if you click the box "hideout of stock items from the catalog" it hides specific variations that are out of stock. It looks weird when a shirt is just showing sizes Small and Large. This is not what I want.

I want to show all variations unless ALL variations are out of stock - then I want to hide the product.

Comment: So its not weird to select a Medium size and return out of stock ? I personally will get frustrated if i go over each product and the size i want its there but out of stock...

Comment: We show list of sizes and in / out of stock / stock quantity at a glance in short description, before selecting a size from the dropdown. Also in the product listview / archive page we show letters for all sizes s m l xl 2x and the sizes are bolded if in stock so you can see from product listview as well. Product listview looks weird as well if under a product it is M L instead of S M L XL 2X.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `woocommerce_product_query` action hook to remove a product if all variation is `outofstock`. code will go in your active theme functions.php file.

```
function hide_product_if_all_variation_and_simple_product_is_outofstock( $q ) {

    global $wpdb;

    // Get ids of products which you want to hide
    $array_of_product_id = array();

    // get all variable product Ids
    $variable_products_ids = wc_get_products( array(
        'limit'  => -1,
        'status' => 'publish',
        'type'   => 'variable',
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));

    // Loop through variable products
    foreach( $variable_products_ids as $variable_id ) {
        $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT COUNT(ID)
            FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
                ON p.ID           =  pm.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type     =  'product_variation'
                AND p.post_status =  'publish'
                AND p.post_parent =  %d
                AND pm.meta_key   =  '_stock_status'
                AND pm.meta_value != 'outofstock'
        ", $variable_id ) );

        $count = $count > 0 ? true : false;         

        if( !$count ){
            $array_of_product_id[] = $variable_id;
        }
    }

    // get all simple product Ids
    $simple_products_ids = wc_get_products( array(
        'limit'  => -1,
        'status' => 'publish',
        'type'   => 'simple',
        'return' => 'ids',
    ));

    // Loop through variable products
    foreach( $simple_products_ids as $simple_id ) {
        $count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT COUNT(ID)
            FROM {$wpdb->posts} p
            INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
                ON p.ID           =  pm.post_id
            WHERE p.post_type     =  'product'
                AND p.post_status =  'publish'
                AND p.ID =  %d
                AND pm.meta_key   =  '_stock_status'
                AND pm.meta_value != 'outofstock'
        ", $simple_id ) );
        
        $count = $count > 0 ? true : false;         

        if( !$count ){
            $array_of_product_id[] = $simple_id;
        }
    }

    if( !empty( $array_of_product_id ) ){
        $q->set( 'post__not_in', $array_of_product_id );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'hide_product_if_all_variation_and_simple_product_is_outofstock' );
```

Comment: Interesting, this looks like it might do what I'm looking for thank you! This won't make any irreversible changes though will it (ie: if i run it, then take it out, will changes revert)?

Comment: Yes, it won't make any irreversible changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Going to try this right away and let you know if it works. Will this also hide non-variable / simple products? BONUS POINTS if it does.

Comment: No, it is only for variable products.

Comment: I don't suppose you have another one that works with simple products too!

Comment: PS I just tried this and it works perfectly, hides all variable products (when all variations are out of stock) when added and they all appear again when this is removed. Exactly what I was looking for!!! Seriously thank you so much, I could not find an answer to this anywhere else and I did a lot of searching before asking here.

All I need to do now is hide simple products out of stock.

Comment: I believe I found my answer to hide both simple and variable products (not just variations) that are out of stock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69725864/using-functions-php-in-woocommerce-how-can-i-hide-simple-products-that-are-out/69726098#69726098

Comment: but in your question, you clearly said you want FOR variation. you should be clear from the beginning.

Comment: Works like a charm. This solution should receive much more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Few easy steps to Hide Out of Stock Products

1. Go to **WooCommerce -> Settings submenu** in the WordPress dashboard.
2. Click on the **Products Tab > Inventory** sub-tab Check the option
3. Out Of Stock Visibility that hides the out of stock products

[image]

Comment: I specifically mentioned this in my question - this is not what i'm looking for and is not an answer to my question.