# Using functions.php - in Woocommerce how can I hide simple products that are out of stock?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My goal is to hide all products that are out of stock.

With the built in Woocommerce hide out of stock option, it hides specific variations out of stock but we only want to hide entire products if all variations are out of stock, or in the case of simple products if it's just plain out of stock.

Someone gave a great answer in this other thread I posted:
[How to hide products if out of stock (if variable product - if all variation are out of stock) in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69718280/how-to-hide-products-if-out-of-stock-if-variable-product-if-all-variation-are)

Their answer hides all variable products if all variations are out of stock but then the question was closed for some reason. Hoping someone can tell me now how to hide simple products that are out of stock.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to my question - this appears to hide all simple and whole variable products (not just variations) that are out of stock.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_meta_query', 
'shop_only_instock_products', 10, 2 );
function shop_only_instock_products( $meta_query, $query ) {
    // Only on shop archive pages
    //if( is_admin() || is_search() || ! is_shop() ) return $meta_query;

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => '_stock_status',
        'value'   => 'outofstock',
        'compare' => '!='
);
return $meta_query;
```